# Moodle crashes after several students try to access or submit a questionnaire

Tags: moodle

My moodle installation is at http://doshape.com/ciberdario. If more that 10 or 20 users try to access or submit to questionnaire, the server crashes and returns error 500.

[image]

[This thread](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=13326) has the same problem but don't have any answers.

The same with [this post](https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/server-error-500-moodle-3-0.71675/).
The same with [this post too](https://x10hosting.com/community/threads/500-error-under-moodle.130542/).
And the same with others. Any solution to this?

Cpanel's log error  or error_log file don't give any feedback about this error... only say

Cannot find session record h25kg7hhk122f7d26rp45l40l6 for user 97, creating new session  or similar.

I change the php limits in my cpanel using the INI MultiPHP

please give me solutions o alternatives; actually I want more than 100 access to the same time

Comment: Please include the relevant info here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on Windows or Linux servers? Have a look at the Known Problems section on [Moodle.org](https://docs.moodle.org/33/en/Windows_installation) regarding Windows installs. If you're using < PHP 7 there are known issues with serving large groups of users.